# Architectural question regarding Interfaces implementation and extensibility

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, mvvm

I've created a sample app, just to test and try out some of wpf's capabilities. I was basically trying out the databinding in wpf, and did the rest of stuff more or less quickly. THen, i faced an arquitectural problem (yes, should have thought in advance before starting coding :) ) and i wanted to know what's the best refactoring solution for it.

I have a simple interface that returns a list of objects, based on a defined process.

```
public interface IDoStuff<out T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Do(string someParam);
        }
```

i've created a couple of implementations for this interface. Then i have a view in wpf, which has a dropdown with hardcoded values, and depending on what you select, instatiates the implementation of the interface and populates some list

```
foreach (var item in new IDoSTuffImplementation1()<MyObj>.Do("imp 1"))
{
    MyObjs.Add(item);
}
```

ater on MyObjs is the DataContext for a listview, and displays things and so on and so forth, but it's out of the main question.

this is all hardcoded and not very nice. If i was ever to implement a new interface, i'd need to add it to the dropdown, and create a new foreach for that specific implementation (more duplicated code)

Ok, here's my impression on making this better/refactoring for extensibility. 
I was thinking a good approach would be to use some kind of MVVM pattern, making the wpf view into a view + viewmodel. the viewmodel would use some kind of IoC like spring, which would (by xml) instantiate one specific implementation of the interface, and inject it to the viewmodel, which would then call its "Do" method and everyone happy. So this way, the only thing that would be needed to do when we implement a new component, is to add it to the xml config file.
Suggestions, Comments? what's the best approach, if any?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see any architecture changes if you provide another implementation of the interface. You already have a good architecture when using MVVM, so the task you are trying to accomplish will not change the architecture, but will extend your application using the architecture.

Comment: yes, but in the current case, the constructor gets a IWorker<Offer>. In the proposed scenario, i would need something like a Dictionary<string,IWorker<Offer>> or something like that, to be able to switch between the appropriate implementation, based on the command. But here, i would have some code very specific to do that switch, either in the button commands or in a switch statement or whatever to check which implementation should be applied. and i think the idea of the mvvm is to try to avoid, amongst other things, this?

Comment: hmm... Maybe you can keep track of IWorker objects in VM and use CommandParameter to identify button's IWorker. If the idea of keeping all IWorker's implementation doesn't sound good to you, you can always initialize VM in code behind and create a VM constructor that accepts the array of IWorker objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change you `Method` to a `Property` instead. And assign that property to `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` property to ease up your coding using data binding.

Comment: this really doesn't help a lot, my main question is regarded to the architecture (and the proposed enhacement), not how to make the databinding.

Comment: You mentioned MVVM and that is why I suggested you use a `Property` instead of a `Method`. MVVM is based on `Notifications`, `Data Binding` and `Commands`. Use `Unity` or `MEF` as an `IoC`.